# MySQL - many foreign keys from one table

Tags: mysql, sql

im making database for game... the problem is I don't know much about databases. Here are my tables i have problem with:

```
CREATE TABLE items(
name VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
atk INT,
def INT,
arm INT,
price_buy SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
price_sell SMALLINT UNSIGNED);

CREATE TABLE equipment (
id_eq INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
head_s VARCHAR(30),
body_s VARCHAR(30),
right_s VARCHAR(30),
left_s VARCHAR(30),
feet_s VARCHAR(30),
slot1 VARCHAR(30),
slot2 VARCHAR(30),
slot3 VARCHAR(30),
slot4 VARCHAR(30),
slot5 VARCHAR(30),
slot6 VARCHAR(30),
slot7 VARCHAR(30),
slot8 VARCHAR(30),
slot9 VARCHAR(30),
slot10 VARCHAR(30).
FOREIGN KEY (head_s) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (body_s) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (right_s) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (left_s) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (feet_s) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (slot1) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (slot2) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (slot3) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (slot4) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (slot5) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (slot6) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (slot7) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (slot8) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (slot9) REFERENCES items(name),
FOREIGN KEY (slot10) REFERENCES items(name));
```

I have doubts about this solution, could anyone tell me is this the right way?

Comment: First you should tell whats your doubt

Comment: Post your error

Comment: `slot10 VARCHAR(30).` this should be `slot10 VARCHAR(30),`

Comment: My doubt is this:
-is that too much of FK for one table
AND can i ad so many FK from only ONE table

Comment: My preference would be to implement an anonymous surrogate unique key on the item table, integer datatype, and have the foreign keys reference that instead of the VARCHAR(30). The number of foreign keys constraints isn't a problem, they can all reference the same table. There will be 14 separate indexes to support the foreign keys. Typically, we'd implement an association table, to handle a variable number of relationships, rather than creating 15 separate foreign key columns. But if this implementation is a good fit for you use case, then there's nothing necessarily wrong with it.

Comment: With InnoDB, I believe that 64 is upper limit on the number of foreign key references to a table. The equipment table, as shown, is going to use up 15 of those 64 on the items table. (Not that we would ever want to anywhere close to 64 foreign key references.)

Comment: Thanks, that's exact answer i was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is not the right way, unless you have exactly 7 slots that are labelled 1 though 7 and you are putting items into some or all of them.

The more typical way is a junction table:

```
create table EquipmentItems (
    EquipmentItemId int primary key auto_increment,
    EquipmentId int,
    ItemId int,
    constraint fk_equipmentitems_equipment foreign key (EquipementId) references Equipement(id_eq),
    constraint fk_equipmentitems_item foreign key (ItemId) references items(ItemId)
);
```

If you look at this carefully, you'll note that I added a synthetic key to `Items`.  This is a good idea for foreign key references, because integers are generally more compact than strings.